# How to catch the event of clicking the "Clear" button in lightning-input type="search"?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html

How to catch the event of clicking the "Clear" button in lightning-input type="search"? In the salesforce documentation, this is not specified, I found a similar question, but for visualforce ^ https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005aZ8QAI, and I could not compose anything useful for myself by analogy. This question concerns LWC and salesforce.

This button:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's stated at very bottom of the [documentation page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation) (emphasis mine)

> **commit**
> The event fired when you press Enter after interacting with the input, or move away from the input so it loses focus. For the input type `search` **the event is also fired when you click the "x" button to clear the search**.

HTML:

```html
<lightning-input
    name="enter-search"
    label="Search when user hits the 'enter' key"
    type="search"
    oncommit={handleClear}
></lightning-input>
```

JS:

```js
handleClear(event) {
    if (!event.target.value.length) {
        console.log('clear');
    }
}
```

Since it's called when the input loses focus too, if you want to handle only the "clear" action you need the if on `target.value.length`.

Comment: In HTML5 they fire "search" event in this scenario, which seems to work in LWC if I press enter but not with "x". 
Moreover, I don't see any difference if i simple use "onchange" to capture clear as well

Comment: @elijah the "onchange" event is fired because pressing the "x" clear the input, but in an onchange handler you have no way to know what's the cause (the "x" or something else). Morever "onchange" is fired everytime you type something, so its handler will be executed a lot more than oncommit one, even when it would be useless for the OP needs. Since the OP asked about catching the "x", handling the commit event would be better.

Comment: I agree it would be fired every time but for "x" I was hoping we can catch that specific event similar to how you did in your snippet when the length of the input is null that's when user clicked on "x".